# how to display list of products horizontally in asp.net with paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to display list of Products in Asp.net like this as shown on Amazon website under **Customers Who Viewed This Item Also Viewed** Section:

http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00J8JTU4G/ref=s9_al_bw_g309_i1?pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-6&pf_rd_r=1NQX58WY3F97WHGQ4NF1&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=561180507&pf_rd_i=1983631031

Is there any control for this in asp.net or any telerik control that would help me to do this and if not then any idea how to do this in asp.net???

I think Ajax call would do but then how would i do paging in that as i havent worked much in asp.net.i am a newbie in asp.net.

So if anybody have done same thing like this please do post your code here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here is the link which uses the Repeater http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satyapriyanayak/display-records-horizontally-in-a-repeater-control/

Comment: You can also use a data list. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79k821wc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: can i do this with ajax as because i want same design like what i shown in the link

Answer (score 0):

you can try with Datalist control .Because DataList have display direction property it might help to you[Display direction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx#display_direction_and_layout)